# USB to UART interface

Tags: usb, uart, msp430, programmer, jtag

I have a project about MSP430, data acquisition then sending through UART to another unit.
I have written and compiled all the codes for ADC and UART in IAR Embedded Workbench. The simulation works fine on Proteus ISIS.
Here is my question:
How can I load these codes into MSP430 to run independently from PC. I mean, two designed boards will be used to communicate with each other.

PS: I have a CP2102 USB-Uart Bridge breakout board. Is it possible to load the codes into MSP430 with this interface? Or should I absolutely use JTAG interface?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need JTAG to program the device. MSP430 also supports bootstrap loading (BSL). A special reset sequence activates the bootstrap loader,

[image]

which uses the UART, with the following settings:

- 9600 bps, half duplex
- 8E1 format (8 data bits, even parity, 1 stop bit

The bootstrap loader is protected with a 256-bit user defined password.

**Further reading**
[MSP430 Programming Via the Bootstrap Loader](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau319b/slau319b.pdf)